# Stackoverflow Scrolling Problem (Video Inside)

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, scrolling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broken 10k tools flag page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109047/broken-10k-tools-flag-page)

There has been an issue for sometime with scrolling. I believe this is due to the fact that the page wants the "Who's Chatting Now" boxes to always be on top. I have uploaded an unlisted video to YouTube to demonstrate this problem. [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DokhJowJEM8).

Comment: huh, nice bug :p

Comment: for a second I thought we can now embed video elements