# The hover text of helpful/declined flag indicators has extraneous spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed

The title text of flag indicators has 2 trailing spaces for some reason. Minor issue, but it looks a bit off:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't want those 2 extra spaces to inconvenience anyone by making them feel unbalanced, or prematurely wear out their monitor by using up extra pixel-fluid, so it will be fixed next build.

Comment: here's another minor annoyance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106062/stackoverflow-scrolling-problem-video-inside

Comment: I've seen a few examples of this before as well. It might be worth doing a `grep` for extra whitespace in `title` attributes across the board, just to check for additional opportunities to preserve that pixel-fluid.

Comment: @hammar if only life were that simple; we don't add extra white-space for fun! This was actually due to optional data that is not shown in all scenarios

Comment: .TRIM() ALL THE STRINGS. http://i.imgur.com/wgl6I.jpg

Comment: @Loic isthatreallyanimprovement?

Comment: @Marc, to be fair, it only remove spaces at the beginning and the end of the string. (I can't believe I'm doing this.) See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx ;)