# Broken 10k tools flag page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

Whenever I click on the "flags" tab on the 10k tools page, I cannot scroll to the bottom of the page. I get about 4/5 of the way and my page jumps back up to about halfway.

I verified this in IE8 and Firefox 7.01. I confirmed the behavior on both SF and SU.

short vid of the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw7-o1QEpNI

Comment: Reproduced in FF 6.02 on Win7.  NoRepro in Chrome 14.0.835.202 m.

Comment: I've been able to repro in Chrome 14.0.835.202

Comment: I posted the same problem here about a month ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106062/stackoverflow-scrolling-problem-video-inside

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that when I searched.

Comment: Not a problem; your post got more upvotes.

Comment: I can reproduce in firefox 3.6.23 (on Fedora 14).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. Sorry 'bout that.