# Profile view tabs will not scroll more than halfway

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page

I seem to be having the same scrolling difficulty mentioned in [Broken 10k tools flag page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109047/broken-10k-tools-flag-page) and [Stackoverflow Scrolling Problem (Video Inside)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106062/stackoverflow-scrolling-problem-video-inside), this time on the profile page.

When viewing any of the lists under the various tabs other than "summary", if there's more than a window full of content, the scroll bar "fights" being scrolled further than about halfway. If I manage to get it to the bottom of the page, it will re-scroll itself up to the top. It's acting as if it is reloading some content below -- and indeed there's a little notification continually popping up in the browser's status bar that something has "Finished loading" -- and constantly resizing the page.

UPDATE: In addition, items with disclosure triangles, such as individual reputation changes or edits, will not display; they open very briefly and immediately re-close.

This was happening with a WebKit browser, OmniWeb 5.11 (v622.15) and Safari 5.0.1 (6533.17.8), on Mac OS X 10.6.8, and continued after I updated to OS X 10.7.3 with Safari v5.1.3. I don't see it with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I can't repro on Win7 Safari 5.1.2; I'll get my mac out tomorrow and check this.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod. There was another Meta question today http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122375/community-user-reputation-tab-acts-up about the same problem and a comment was made there too about no-repro on Windows. I'm willing to concede that I may just need to run an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed that at some point this was repaired. I've been working around it so long that I have no idea when, or why, or how, but I no longer have the problem I described. It could be due to whatever change was made to resolve the similar problem reported in [Continuous refreshing of pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/continuous-refreshing-of-pages#comment326862_122845), although that was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have Safari 5.1.2 on my OS X version 10.7.2, so I can't test with your setup.

Fortunately (for the poor dev that would have had to fix this :), I can't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Although, I just encountered a bug of my own when posting this answer where the page wouldn't properly load, so looks like there's be work after all.

Comment: Okay, thanks for looking anyways.