# Community user reputation tab acts up

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Profile view tabs will not scroll more than halfway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/profile-view-tabs-will-not-scroll-more-than-halfway)

When I was looking at the users on the site, I found the ["Robot" user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation). When I went to the reputation tab, it wouldn't let me scroll down past a certain point. It would just keep pushing me up to the beginning of the reputation. Is this supposed to happen? If it's helpful, I'm using Safari.

Comment: What version of Safari?  I have no problems in FF.

Comment: @MatthewRead Safari 5.0.2

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me!

Comment: @TimStone Should I delete this? The only reason I wouldn't is because that doesn't have any answers either.

Comment: That's up to you, really. Hopefully either way it'll be attended to sooner than later, since I imagine that's rather annoying. For what it's worth, I'm unable to reproduce this on Safari 5.1 / Windows 7.

Comment: Going to close this, but [as I said here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/profile-view-tabs-will-not-scroll-more-than-halfway#comment325384_122230), I'll check it tomorrow on my mac.